# How can the VPS access the IPMI addresses as its host machine?

Tags: networking, vps

I created a VPS(CentOS 6.9) on the Windows Server 2008 Dedicated Server.

[image]

In the Windows Server 2008 Dedicated Server, there are two interface, one is for public network, and the other is for interior network to manage the IPMI addresses.

you can see the interfaces snapshot:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

the "本地连接 5" is `121.1.1.1` is for public network, the "本地连接" `172.18.1.252` is for interior network the IPMI management.

this is the configuration of "本地连接", pay attention we did not set the gateway because we think there is no need for accessing other network at that time:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

---

In the VPS, there are `eth0` and `eth1` interface.

the `eth0` I configured a public IP address, and the `eth1` is configured like this:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

code is:

```
DEVICE=eth1
HWADDR=00:xxxx
TYPE=Ethernet 
UUID=xxx
ONBOOT=yes
NM_CONTROLLED=yes
BOOTPROTO=static
IPADDR=172.18.1.251
NETWORK=255.255.255.0
```

and in the settings of the VPS, the `eth1` is using the "interior-ipmi", which is "本地连接 6", you can see the network in the second snapshot upper, the Dedicated Server's "本地连接 6" ip address is `172.18.1.250/24`(you can check in upper snapshot).

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

---

My problem is, in the VPS, I can access the Dedicated Server's `172.18.1.250/24`, and I also can from Dedicated Server to access the VPS's `172.18.1.251/24`.
but I can not access the `172.18.1.252/24` from VPS, also can not access the `172.18.1.2/24` and other IPMI address. in the Dedicated Server I can access those.

My purpose is access all the IPMI address(`172.18.1.*`) from the VPS. but now there is something waywardness there, who can help with this?

Comment: What do you mean by "IPMI" here? Is it just a normal 'management' network, or is it supposed to be an onboard BMC/iLO/IDRAC controller?

Comment: @grawity this is BMC controller related.

Comment: Then I'm quite surprised that the BMC controller's interface and IP address are visible to the host OS. On all servers I've worked with, the BMC IPMI port (or vlan) configuration is completely separate from the host...

Comment: @grawity Please be attention the Dedicated Server is controller machine for all the machines through IPMI addresses. I want to created an VPS as the same function as Dedicated Server.